# ASP.NET Core use IAsyncEnumerate as input parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-streaming, iasyncenumerable

In an ASP.NET Core WebApi Application I succesfully used `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` as return type by the controller.
Now I'd like to know if(and how) i can use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` as input parameter.
Something like this :

```
[Route("Operation")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task Operation(IAsyncEnumerable<Entity> commands)
{
        await foreach (Entity command in commands)
        {
            // do something
        }
}
```

I searched some articles but I found only articles on how to return it.

Is there a way to use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` as an input parameter?

Comment: The controller action will not be called before whole request is processed and parameters deserialized. So there is no need of IAsyncEnumerable<T> because all data is already loaded.

Comment: Since the list of command may be long, I hoped there is a way to start process the command list without wait whole list is deserializated in memory.

Comment: Afaik it is possible only through manual parsing body.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-6.0#avoid-reading-large-request-bodies-or-response-bodies-into-memory

Comment: sorry, i couldnt  found how manual parsing body in the link you sent

Comment: If you are using Asp.Net Core 6.0 and you are available to use [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0) then while formatting using System.Text.Json, MVC no longer buffers IAsyncEnumerable<T> instances. You could see the detailed information in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/6.0/iasyncenumerable-not-buffered-by-mvc)